# Clean way to split a pandas DataFrame() into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

My apologies if that exists somewhere -- I couldn't find the right keywords.

I have a very simple `pd.DataFrame()` that looks like this

```
articles = pd.DataFrame(
                [(0, "Once upon.."),
                 (1, "It happened.."),
                 (2, "The story.."),
                 (3, "So many.."),
                 (4, "How long.."),
                 (5, "It's been..")],
            columns=["article_id", "article"])
```

Such that

```
>>> articles

    article_id  article
0   0   Once upon..
1   1   It happened..
2   2   The story..
3   3   So many..
4   4   How long..
5   5   It's been..
```

I'd just like to split that column into 3 columns (whatever the order, but let's say keeping the order) i.e. something like this :

```
    article1_id article1    article2_id article2    article3_id article3
0   0   Once upon.. 1   It happened..   2   The story..
1   3   So many..   4   How long..  5   It's been..
```

For now I have some ugly thing like that (which works) :

```
tmp1 = articles.loc[::3].reset_index(); del tmp1['index'];
tmp1.columns = ['article1_id', 'article1']
tmp2 = articles.loc[1::3].reset_index(); del tmp2['index'];
tmp2.columns = ['article2_id', 'article2']
tmp3 = articles.loc[2::3].reset_index(); del tmp3['index'];
tmp3.columns = ['article3_id', 'article3']

pd.concat([tmp1, tmp2, tmp3], axis=1, ignore_index=False).head()
```

But I'm sure `pandas` offers something cleaner...

Comment: Can we do this before creating the dataframe? Or are you looking for the pandas operation for this? May I also ask why we do this? Seems quite wrong. (And with why.. I'm just curious if we could think differently)

Comment: Rather do this after creating it - there must be a quick way. I need to create CSVs with such group of three articles per CSV line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we are looking for array.reshape()

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
                [(0, "Once upon.."),
                 (1, "It happened.."),
                 (2, "The story.."),
                 (3, "So many.."),
                 (4, "How long.."),
                 (5, "It's been.."),
                 (6, "It's been.."),
                 (7, "It's been..")],
            columns=["article_id", "article"])

# New cols (let them define the length of reshape)
cols = ['article1_id','article1','article2_id','article2','article3_id','article3']

# If size of dataframe is not divisable by len(cols) add rows
# Can be removed if certain of length.
while df.size % len(cols) != 0:
    df.loc[len(df)] = ('','')

df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(df.size//len(cols),len(cols)), columns=cols)

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
  article1_id     article1 article2_id       article2 article3_id     article3
0           0  Once upon..           1  It happened..           2  The story..
1           3    So many..           4     How long..           5  It's been..
2           6  It's been..           7    It's been..
```

.to_csv():

```
,article1_id,article1,article2_id,article2,article3_id,article3
0,0,Once upon..,1,It happened..,2,The story..
1,3,So many..,4,How long..,5,It's been..
2,6,It's been..,7,It's been..,,
```

Comment: Thanks, that `.reshape()` is exactly what I needed -- didn't remember it. I think you meant "add lines" in your comment before the while ? Nice sanity check btw.

Comment: @Arnaud Yes, I meant rows. Thanks.